# iSQLPlus not starting on Port 80

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to change the port for iSQLPlus on my Oracle DB server, by making changes in the file `http-web-site.xml`.

When I change the port to 80, in this file, the iSqlPlus doesn't start. I can nether connect over a browser or telnet to it, even from the host machine itself. On the command line, however, it does not give any errors.

I have tried changing it to other ports that is 8080 and 5560, it is running fine with no problems there.

**I am using `Oracle 10.2.0_10`.**

Comment: There's a crazy gang over at ServerFault.com who probably know the answer to this one off the top of their heads. Voted to migrate.

Comment: I have posted the same question at SF, which has been viewed just once, in he last one hour. Hence I request the 'Gang' here to please look into it...

Comment: Silly question but are you sure nothing else is running on port 80? It's easy to happen and not know: for instance the Oracle HTTP server runs on port 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on Unix you need to be root to run a service with port under 1024
For a more complete answer see https://serverfault.com/questions/38461/is-there-still-a-reason-why-binding-to-port-1024-is-only-authorized-for-root-on